# Basic authentication to access assembla rest apis from android

Tags: android

I want to use assembla apis from android environment for my project.
I am trying to do basic authentication as follow :

```
String authentication = "username:password";
String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(authentication.getBytes(), 0);    

     URL url = new URL("https://www.assembla.com/");

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.connect();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());

        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
```

I am getting 400 and Bad Request in output.
is there something wrong with URL that i am using or some other thing is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677293/problem-with-basic-access-authentication-in-file-downloader). You need to use Base64.NO_WRAP flag when encoding username-password pair:

```
String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(authentication.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

By default the Android Base64 util adds a newline character to the end of the encoded string. This invalidates the HTTP headers and causes the "Bad request".

The Base64.NO_WRAP flag tells the util to create the encoded string without the newline character thus keeping the HTTP headers intact.

Comment: Confirmed to work. I actually needed this to add HTTP Basic Auth to Android DownloadManager Request header. Thanks a lot man, very very useful !

Answer (score 0):

**REST API with HTTP Authentication Output:- I got the result**

```
String authentication = "username:password";

String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(authentication.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);


HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

conn.setDoOutput(true);

 conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

  conn.connect();

 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 

 wr.write( data ); 

 wr.flush(); 

  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;

 while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {

   // Append server response in string

   sb.append(line + "\n");


  }

 Content = sb.toString();
```