# Gson toJson is adding "\n" to the end of my property

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm converting my object to JSON in Android using Gson.toJson(object) but for some reason it is adding a `\n` to the end of one of the properties in the object. Any help? Thank you.

My object is a ticket.

Logging the TicketId property value returns:

```
 7NyzwRaic5xGgDRm9r1s6u+C1hQ/fOVOp+a5hlIYjJOdctPKOQAses0qRdy2RaZr
```

Using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ticket);
```

Logging the output JSON returns this:

```
json: {"UserEmail":"jon@mail.com","TicketId":"7NyzwRaic5xGgDRm9r1s6u+C1hQ/fOVOp+a5hlIYjJOdctPKOQAses0qRdy2RaZr\n","Used":false,"EventPrice":0.0,"EventId":0}
```

You can see there is a "\n" added at the end of the TicketId property value.

Comment: If you quote the output you're talking about, and the code producing it, people may be able to help you. We/They want to, honest, but you have to meet us/them part-way.

Comment: Does that help? It's literally 1 method between the two logs outputs so the only thing that could be adding the "/n" is the gson.toJson() method.

Comment: @ jon: It's much more likely that there's a newline at the end of the ticket ID, and that however you're logging the ticket ID doesn't make that apparent. Obviously, `Gson#toJson` is not randomly adding newlines to strings.

Comment: It turns out the Android built in Base64 utility adds a new line to every string. I needed to change the flag from Base64.DEFAULT to Base64.NO_WRAP.

Thank you for your help T.J. Crowder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. Android's built in Base64 utility adds a New Line to the end of a string  and I am getting the ticketID using said utility. I had to set the flag for converting the bytes to a string using the `Base64.NO_WRAP` flag.

I have no idea why it wasn't showing up in the logcat for the ticketId.

[Basic authentication to access assembla rest apis from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106028/basic-authentication-to-access-assembla-rest-apis-from-android/7106243#7106243)

Comment: How exactly do you do that?